# How to write the file `nginx.service` on centos 7.2?

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx from source on centos 7.2,and I need a file ——`nginx.service` .
There is an example of `mysqld.service`,
https://superuser.com/a/384525/577295

I imitate it and write like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx --defaults-file=/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf  --socket=/var/run/nginx/nginx.sock
User=nginx
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/usr

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Question:**
1、Is there anything missing out？
2、Is there anything not right？
3、There is no `--socket=/var/run/nginx/nginx.sock`,do I need write it?What is the content of this file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay to me at first glance. Did you try it? You don't need to create the file, although you do need to make sure the directory `/var/run/nginx` exists.